# Error when using updateData function in Firebase on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I tried to use the updateData(fields: [AnyHashable : Any]) function to update an array in a document. It was working fine after a while I got a really strange error which I was unable to resolve, here's the error message:

```
global function '__designTimeString(_:fallback:)' requires that 'AnyHashable' conform to 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build Data.swift

Compiling failed: global function '__designTimeString(_:fallback:)' requires that 'AnyHashable' conform to 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'

Data.swift:115:17: error: global function '__designTimeString(_:fallback:)' requires that 'AnyHashable' conform to 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'
                __designTimeString("#64647.[4].[6].[3].modifier[2].arg[0].value.[0].key.[0].value", fallback: "reviews"): FieldValue.arrayUnion([id])
                ^
SwiftUI.__designTimeString:1:13: note: where 'T' = 'AnyHashable'
public func __designTimeString<T>(_ key: String, fallback: T) -> T where T : ExpressibleByStringLiteral
```

I have been looking around but couldn't really find much details on this kind of errors, please help :(

here's the part of my code that caused this error:

```
db.collection("restaurants").document(restaurantId).updateData([
     "reviews": FieldValue.arrayUnion([id])
     ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error updating document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully updated")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error is being produced on the `FieldValue.arrayUnion([id])` part. As shown in the [Firestore documentation for adding data with Swift](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), the field has to be quoted, so you can replace:

```
"reviews": FieldValue.arrayUnion([id])
```

for

```
"reviews": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `updateData`, the keys need to be `String`s.

Have you considered using Codable? Import `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`, and then save data using `db.collection("restaurants").addDocument(from: review)`. More details here: [SwiftUI: Mapping Firestore Documents using Swift Codable](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/swiftui-mapping-firestore-documents-using-swift-codable-589b6bfe462d)