# updateData function in Firebase is unable to recognise document field

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Not sure if I've put down my question clearly but I'm facing a similar issue as [Error when using updateData function in Firebase on SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637087/error-when-using-updatedata-function-in-firebase-on-swiftui) when I wanted to insert a new element in the array under one of the documents.

I realised that using the updateData function results in a crash no matter what.

Here is part of my code:

```
let temp = db.collection("users").document("IV9vtchAAcKy")
        temp.updateData([
            "friends": FieldValue.arrayUnion("Simon")
        ])
```

I've tried following the answers given but they did not seem to work for me. It seems that it is unable to recognize "friends" as a field under the document as the error given to me was:

```
global function '__designTimeString(_:fallback:)' requires that 'AnyHashable' conform to 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'

AuthenticationState.swift:148:13: error: global function '__designTimeString(_:fallback:)' requires that 'AnyHashable' conform to 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'
```

where I think "friends" is not conforming to 'AnyHashable' and hence the error.

I'm still really new to Firebase and Swift and would appreciate any advice given, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

.arrayUnion adds elements in an array format. You are simply missing the brackets.

Replace:

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion("Simon")
```

with:

```
FieldValue.arrayUnion(["Simon"])
```

[Firebase Firestore: Append/Remove items from document array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58127209/2185588)

Comment: thank you for answering, I think I missed out the square brackets while I was pasting over as I was trying to conceal the real name. I also found out that I simply need to wrap "friends" in AnyHashable, so AnyHashable("friends") would work for my code